# Free customizable rss feed newsletter service

Tags: free, feeds, feedburner, newsletter, mailchimp

I'm desperately searching for a newsletter system for my association. We have a site from which to fetch the news and I want them to be sent regularly to the people who subscribe. 
I would like to get the rss from this site and send them in the newsletter. I also want to be able to customize the layout of the mails.
And since we are an NGO, I would possibly have this for free :)

I was thinking about feedburner but you cannot customize the aspect, then I though about mailchimp, but we are a pretty big association and adding the people who would remain subscribed to the newsletter even after they left the association, I'm afraid we would pass the free quota in few years!

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: "I'm afraid we would pass the free quota in few years". So use Mailchimp for a few years. Premature optimisation is evil - in 2015 your needs will be different.

Comment: <a href="http://www.feedburner.com/">Feedburner</a> can convert rss feeds into emails: unfortunately you can't customize it.

Comment: We opted for PHPList. 

Actually we're having some problem with it. We are not able to have the rss mail sent... Furthermore you can have only one feed per list.